# How to properly install nvm/node/npm in AWS EC2 for multiple developers?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2, nvm

Trying to understand how node is supposed to be installed for multiple developers in AWS EC2 as an administrator. (I am also one of the devs).

I have an EC2 server with nginx running on port 80. Should I now go to the webroot and install nvm/node/npm as ec2-user?  Or my own user, and then all the other users after?  (No one can actually use the ec2-user account except server admins.)

How about other developers who need to use node? I was hoping to install nvm/node/npm for everyone in advance who needs it so that they could use it immediately after getting access to the server, but maybe everyone should install nvm/node/npm themselves?

Or it would be nice if there is a way to install it as ec2-user and then share it with all the users properly/securely?  What's the right way to set this up?

(When I ran through this myself as my own user and installed nvm for the first time in EC2 Linux 2 AMI, I noticed that when I switched to another user or root, the "node -v" command didn't work for other accounts - and basically I'm trying to do an install that covers all the users.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, in AWS EC2, you need only one user and one NodeJS running. I would suggest below set-up for development and deployment.

1. Let all developers have their dev environment set-up in their local machines.
2. Let developers check-in their code to Github or a similar repository.
3. Using a CI/CD pipeline. Integrate the code and build the code and deploy it into EC2.
4. Instead of EC2, I would recommend using AWS Beanstalk.

If this makes sense for you, we can elaborate this into a solution and implement it.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  I will set everything up as ec2-user then, set up a Github repo, and use AWS CodePipeline for steps 1-3.  Beanstalk I do not know how to use yet so I might have to research this next, but I still have quite a bit of learning to do with node first...thank you very much!